# Select item from array with React Router v4 query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to implement the following:

I have an array of jobs which I list by category:

localhost:3000/jobs

When user selects item, it lists all related jobs to this category:

localhost:3000/jobs/search?q=Category

From react router I get search param and filter array of jobs by category, then

show this list of jobs like so:

```
Position 1
Position 2
Position 3
```

Now whenever user clicks on position, I want to render it's details above. I assume my url should show something like this:

localhost:3000/search?q=Category&jobid=123

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach to show the job details.

Instead of using URL parameters, you can create a new route, something like `jobs/:jobId` using React router, and in each job object, you can render the link. something like this:

```
// ... the usual imports
class App extends React.Component {

  // your helper methods here to load the state

  render() {
    const {jobs} = this.state; // might be from state or redux
    return (
      <div>
        {jobs.map(job => <Link to=`/jobs/${job.id}`>Job {{job.id}}</Link>)}

        <Switch>
          <Route path='/jobs/:jobId' component={JobDetail}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class JobDetail extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = { job: null }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const {match} = this.props;
    const {jobId} = match.params;
    // maybe do an API call here to fetch the job details
    // and store response on state
    // something like: this.setState({...this.state, job: response.job});
  }

  render() {
    const {job} = this.state;
    return(
       <div>
           <h1>Job Details</h1>
           {/* present your job details here if not null */}
           {{job}}
       </div>
    );
  }

}
```